# Highchart Column hides in the middle of Highchart Scroll bar

Tags: javascript, charts, scrollbar, highcharts

I am using highstock for scrollbar in highcharts. It is working fine, but when I move scroll forward first of last column of chart hides from chart window. I want to show minimum 3 columns at any point of time. I have used min : 0 and max : 2 in chart configuration.

[image]

`Here is fiddle for the issue` [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dum6m6mq/)

Answer (score 0):

If category is not full in visible area then column will not be visible either.
If you want to show minimum 3 columns at any time then you could increase max by 1.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dum6m6mq/7/

```
xAxis : {
                min : 0,
                max : 3,
...
```